# Selecting an item in an list box (asp.net 3.5)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, listbox

Say I have a listbox lb, which I initialize using:

```
lb.DataSource = wordList \\wordList is a list of strings
lb.DataBind()
```

The listbox is initialized perfectly, and everything that should appear there does.

However, now I select one of items in the listbox with my mouse (coloring it dark blue, in case anyone wondered what I meant in "select"), and perform the following test:

```
 If lb.SelectedIndex <> -1 Then
        DoSomething()
 EndIf
```

or the test:

```
If Not lb.SelectedItem Is Nothing Then
            DoSomething()
     EndIf
```

etc..

Either way, when debugging it keeps not entering the if blocks, claiming of course that
lb.selectedindext IS -1, lb.SelectedItem IS nothing, and so on.

What am I doint wrong? Why doesn't it recognise my selections??
10x

Comment: If my answer helps you, please, set it as accepted :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible that you do the DataBind() of the listBox also in the postback?
Maybe you need to put it (the binding) in a

```
if (!IsPostback) { .. }
```

to ensure you're not losing your client's select.

Answer (score 0):

Is your listbox setup as a multi-select listbox?  If so, you have to use the SelectedItems collection to iterate through all the selected items.